# Best way of doing a "remove layout"?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a application that has an activity that shows message logs. The thing is the user must to be able to select some messages and then delete them as you can do when you want to remove some sms messages.

Which is the best way of doing that? Adding more details:

Here is a capture with the messages only.

[image]

Here is a capture with the selection layout.

[image]

I want to know how they do it to show the `CheckBoxes`. Did they use two layouts?

Comment: some code please ..so that we get know what you are using ...

Comment: I will post some code later, im not in the PC... Anyway im using a listview with an adapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanna know how they do it to show the checkbox, does they use 2
>   layouts?

I doubt they use two layouts files. As the rows are very similar it very easy to switch from the layout that doesn't have the `CheckBox` to the layout that does have the `CheckBox` just by changing the visiblity. A way to do it would be to have a flag in your adapter that indicates the presence of the `CheckBox` in the rows and update the `CheckBox` visibility based on that flag:

```
boolean checkStatus = false;

//...

public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     //...
     if (checkStatus) {
          checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show the CheckBox for each row
     } else {
          checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide the CheckBox for each row
     }
     //...
}
```

Then when it's time to show those `CheckBoxes`(on a `Button` click, menu click etc) you just have to set the `checkStatus` flag to the desired value(`true` for `CheckBoxes` present, `false` otherwise) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Of course you could use two layouts, one that contains the `CheckBox` and one that doesn't have it. But, generally, you would use two layouts in a `ListView` when the two layouts are very(or substantial) different(which is not your case). To implement the two layouts you would have to use the methods `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount`.

```
boolean checkStatus = false;

public int getViewTypeCount() {
     return 2; // you have two layouts
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if (checkStatus) {
          return 1;
     } else {
          return 0;
     }
}
```

Then in your `getView` method:

```
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     int which = getItemViewType(position)
     // make a switch statement and inflate the correct layout file
     // based on the which variable if the convertView is null
     // do stuff;
}
```

Of course when it's time to show the `CheckBoxes` you would have to set the `checkStatus` flag again and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: Thanks that's what i wanna know.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a listView and an adapter , my guess is that the adapter holds a (pure java) list of the messages . so , when the user removes an item , remove it from the list , based on the item's location in the list .

right after that , call [`notifyDataSetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter . that's it .

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying, and i already know it but my question is more related with a visual matter and layouts. Do i need 2 layouts and toggle between them? Or is there any other way?

Comment: no , the listView will be updated according to its adapter . you really don't have to toggle or create anything.

Comment: I guess you are not understanding me or i'm not explaining very well. I need to know how to show or hide checkbox for selecting the messages that would be deleted. If i need to use 2 layouts or show or hide a checkbox column. Or something like that.

Comment: that's a ui design question . i would prefer using a layout (relativeLayout or linearLayout) which contains the checkbox for all of the items in the listview. in case the user is in deletion mode , i would set the visibility of the checkboxes to visibile . that's just my preferred way , but i'm sure everyone can do something else.

Comment: if the answer has helped you , please tick it with "V" . also , for more information about listView , check out this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70